# Remove CSS class for Particular element in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have defined Css class

```
form input[type="text"], form input[type="email"], form input[type="password"], form select, form textarea {
    background: url("../images/input-bg.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 4px 5px;
}
```

now when i use Input in html css affects to all input on the form
because i have used [form] in the css.
but i do not want to affect css to some input texboxes..

how can i achive this ?

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it the other way, just add other classes to inputs you don't want to be affected by that rule. Something like this.

*Edited adding comment suggestion*

```
/* General rule for inputs */
form input[type="text"], form input[type="email"], form input[type="password"], form select, form textarea {
    background: url("../images/input-bg.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding: 4px 5px;
}

/* Specific rule for inputs */
form input[type="text"].reset-inputs, form input[type="email"].reset-inputs, form input[type="password"].reset-inputs, form textarea.reset-inputs, form select.reset-inputs {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: That won't work because of CSS's specificity rules. Make the second selector `form input.reset-inputs` and then it'll be specific enough to over-ride the one above it.

Comment: You are right, I was just trying to show the way. Thanks a lot for the feedback, answer updated :)

Comment: There's no need to go as far as you have in adding the attribute selector though. Just `form input.reset-inputs, form textarea.reset-inputs, form select.reset-inputs` would do it because class selectors far outweigh attribute selectors. http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity

Answer (score 1):

you can add a class for the input boxes you dont want an effect and override the other one:

```
<input class="noeffect"/>


form input.noeffect {
   background: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Would need to have `background: none !important;` in order to override. Adding the class, alone, will not be enough as the effect is applied to `form input`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the input felds you like to affect:

```
html: <input class="here" ... />

css: form input.here[type="text"]
```

Or create a div region with your input's in it:

```
<div class="here">
    <input /><input /><input />
</div>

css: form .here input[type="text"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several properties like `:nth-child()` `:last-child,` `:first-child` etc:

Like this:

```
form input[type="text"] + form input[type="text"] {
background:none;

}
```

or

```
form input[type="text"]:nth-child(2n){
  background:none;
}
```

or

give a class to it

```
form input.diff{
 background:none;
}
```